# Initialize a pair of vectors with a certain length and same numbers

Tags: c++, vector, initialization, std-pair

What I want to achieve is to initialize a pair of a vector with a certain *length* and a certain *initialization number*

I know that a vector can be initialized with the same elements:

```
std::vector v(length, number);
```

and a pair:

```
std::pair<int> p(number, number);
```

so combining those two together I thought of:

```
std::pair<std::vector<int>, std::vector<int>> pv((length, number),(length, number));
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
size_t length = 5;
int number = 0;
std::pair<std::vector<int>, std::vector<int>> pv(std::vector<int>(length, number), std::vector<int>(length, number));
```

Comment: hold on I can only mark this answer as correct in 6 minutes

Answer (score 1):

You could use braces ([list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization)) from C++11.

```
std::pair<std::vector<int>, std::vector<int>> pv({length, number}, {length, number});
```

Comment: was about to post this XD